# RegEx - get data between something

Tags: regex, angular

I need to get the `id` which is in a link.

https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/details.html?id=252619802&damageUnrepaired=NO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED

My regex till now is `id\=[0-9]*` but it filters also the `"id="`

I could do another regex which search for digits in the last match but is there an other option?

Comment: As there's no other number, why not just `\d+`? But you could always use a *lookbehind* to check for `id=`.

Comment: except for MSIE there also exists [`URL`](http://caniuse.com/#search=URL) and [`searchParams.get`](http://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams) ... `var url = new URL('https://suchen.mobile.de/fahrzeuge/details.html?id=252619802&damageUnrepaired=NO_DAMAGE_UNREPAIRED'); console.log('id : ', url.searchParams.get('id'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the digits in a [group](https://regex101.com/r/nBV5ht/1) if you use for example javascript:

`id=(\d+)`

Or use a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=id=)\d+` in your [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tltI3N/1) if this is supported.

Comment: ... do you test the RegExp before you post it? ...`var regX = (/(?<=id=)\d+/);` raises in ffx and chrome an exception **SyntaxError: invalid regexp group**

Comment: @PeterSeliger Good remark,  have updated my answer for the javascript and the pcre version.